# Alerts on Application Gateway Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-application-gateway

I have two application gateways in azure whenever one goes down it switches to the other, but VM (outside of azure) is in on-premises.

How to generate an alert when one application gateway **is Unavailable**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monitoring application gateways is pretty straight forwards, if one gateway is down it would mean all backends are down and you can generate alerts on that easily using azure monitor and the alerts.

Documentation how to do this can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/monitor-application-gateway)

Comment: thanks for the reply @Matt Douhan ,small clarification against what metrics the query has to be done. ....   Sum Total Requests,
Sum Failed Requests,
Sum Response Status by HttpStatus,
Sum Throughput,
Sum CurrentConnections,
Avg Healthy Host Count By BackendPool HttpSettings,
Avg Unhealthy Host Count By BackendPool HttpSettings

Comment: @Ajay I have not looked into the details but if you avg unhealthy Host count is 0 tha wojld probably work